# How can I add new page on GitHub page sharing the same theme with index.md?

Tags: html, github, yaml, markdown, github-pages

Currently, I have one main page on my GitHub account (`https://<username>.github.io/`). I would like to add another page that shares the same theme with the main page.(`https://<username>.github.io/<new_page>`)

I have tried adding new markdown file (e.g. <new_page>.md) with this:

```
---
layout: page
title: "<new_page>"
permalink: /<new_page>/
---
```

at the top of file, but it didn't work. Also, tried to add `theme: <same_theme>` but it didn't work as well.

Note that the theme that I used is `jekyll-theme-minimal`.

Below is the example of my page:
[image]

I would like to add another page with the same header on the left-hand side pane, just vary the right-hand side content.

Answer (score -3):

**step 1**
create folder in current index
example:

C:\Users\Jota W\Desktop\folder with index.html(folder1)\ other folder with index(folder2)
finish.

**step 2** vscode LINK html, < a class="nav-item nav-link" href="FOLDER2/">FOLDER2 NAME< /a>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).