# How can I create new page on the GitHub page with the same theme as the main page?

Tags: github, yaml, markdown, github-pages

I am creating the Github page for showing my profile. My first page is the main one (`https://<username>.github.io/`) to show an overview of my bio. And, I would like to add another page that shares the same theme with the main page (`https://<username>.github.io/<new_page>`). I would like to use this page to showcase my projects. Note that the theme that I used is `jekyll-theme-minimal`.

I have tried to add new page but it is not the same theme as shown below:

[image]

I would like the new page to be like this that shares the same header on the left-hand side pane, just vary the right-hand side content.:

[image]

I have found the question that asked about this point but it seems to not have good answer.

[How can I add new page on GitHub page sharing the same theme with index.md?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70240570/how-can-i-add-new-page-on-github-page-sharing-the-same-theme-with-index-md)

Comment: [this repository](https://github.com/BorealBlizzard/borealblizzard.github.io) has a multi-page setup hosted [here](https://borealblizzard.github.io/). going through the repo and it's `Raw` code will show you how to add frontmatter and structure your repo.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me instantly is to create a new `.md` file with the page content I want on a new page and in my main page link to this new `.md` file. For example, my main page uses `README.md`, I also have `about.md` within an `/other-pages/` folder, thus, somewhere within `README.md` I add

```markdown
[link to my ABOUT page](other-pages/about.md)
```

I never had to bother thinking about `jekyll` or front-matter, etc.

Answer (score 0):

- In the root of your publishing source, create a new file for your page called PAGE-NAME.md, replacing PAGE-NAME with a meaningful filename for the page.
- Add the following YAML frontmatter to the top of the file, replacing PAGE TITLE with the page's title and URL-PATH with a path you want for the page's URL. For example, if the base URL of your site is `https://octocat.github.io` and your URL-PATH is `/about/contact/`, your page will be located at `https://octocat.github.io/about/contact`.

```
layout: page
title: "PAGE TITLE"
permalink: /URL-PATH/
```

- Below the frontmatter, add content for your page.

[Source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-content-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll#adding-a-new-page-to-your-site)

Comment: I have tried to add those code on top of the file but it didn't work for me. It gave me the plain page as shown in the image above.

Comment: can you add the frontmatter to your question?